# Alter the data of a matrix as function of one of its columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of which I want to edit one of the columns based on another of the columns. The column I want to edit has numeric values and the reference column has string values.

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
M = matrix(c(1,4,7,6,5,a,b,c,a,b),5,2)
1   a    
4   b    
7   c    
6   a
5   b
```

And I want to multiply by a factor the rows where the second column has the "a" value, to get a matrix like this (for example by multiplying by 2):

```
2   a    
4   b    
7   c    
12  a
5   b
```

Comment: Sidenote: A matrix can hold only 1 type, characters in your case. Maybe you need a data frame/list ? Also those letters should probably be quoted. "a", "b" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, matrices should only consist of one class type (e.g., character or integer or numeric etc.). I suggest using a data frame for columns of different class types.

```
d <-  data.frame(num = c(1,4,7,6,5),str = c("a","b","c","a","b"))
d[d$str == "a","num"] <- d[d$str == "a","num"]*2

> d
  num str
1   2   a
2   4   b
3   7   c
4  12   a
5   5   b
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
df1 <- type.convert(as.data.frame(M), as.is = TRUE)
df1$V1 <- ifelse(df1$V2 == 'a', df1$V1 * 2, df1$V1)
```